# Java 8 InetAddress.getHostName doesn't work for localhost

Tags: java-8, java-7, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

I just upgraded java 7 to 8. All test cases are failed to connect to local database.

I found out a bug report related to java 8 upgrade and it points to 'localhost' issue, so I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 for all database urls. Then it works.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CWD-3981

> InetAddress.getHostName behaviour has changed java 7->8 to the effect
>   that in 8 it returns localhost unless you have the FQHN of localhost
>   as the first alias in /etc/hosts

According to this link, I can still use localhost if I set /etc/hosts correctly. Here is my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Is that correct settings?

This is my database url in application.conf.

```
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/prdata"
```

Comment: I don’t get your question. The sentence you have cited says that `getHostName` *does* return `"localhost"` *unless* you take actions to achieve something different. Why do you think you have to do something if you *want* to use `"localhost"`?

Comment: I edited the question. This is just one post I found related to the error I got.  Then I change my database url in application.conf from localhost to 127.0.0.1, it works now. But I want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a call to getHostName is made during database connection..

Have you tried with the "jdbc" on your connection url?

From the documentation:

```
# Default database configuration using PostgreSQL database engine
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://database.example.com/playdb"
```

So I'd guess yours would look something like:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/prdata"
```

I Tried with a play-2.4 + Java 8 app and I get a "Configuration error[Cannot connect to database]" if the "jdbc" is not present.